# Can I embed text in word document with special attributes of my own

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am working on a project where I have to create a MSWord document. The text in this document is obtained from a special database. Now what I want is that apart from the visible text, I want to embed some special text (for example, some ids) in MSWord which is never made visible to the user. Basically this text should be saved as a special attribute to the  xml tag. Also it should be possible to read back this attribute.

Can someone please guide me. I have tried reading a lot but have no clue still. I do not even know if I can add any such special attribute to . Also if it is possible, then how should I do so.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved I believe using OpenXML.

Look at the Vanish element... [Taken from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc547047%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

**Update:** As vanish will not serve your requirements take a look at [Add Custom XML Parts to Document-Level Customizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb608627%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Add a new CustomXMLPart object to the CustomXMLParts collection in the document. The CustomXMLPart contains the XML string that you want to store in the document.

```
private void AddCustomXmlPartToDocument()
{
    string xmlString =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
        "<employees xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/vsto/samples\">" +
            "<employee>" +
                "<name>Karina Leal</name>" +
                "<hireDate>1999-04-01</hireDate>" +
                "<title>Manager</title>" +
            "</employee>" +
        "</employees>";

    Office.CustomXMLPart employeeXMLPart = this.CustomXMLParts.Add(xmlString, missing);
}
```

Add the AddCustomXmlPartToDocument method to the ThisDocument class in a document-level project for Word.

Call the method from other code in your project. For example, to create the custom XML part when the user opens the document, call the method from the ThisDocument_Startup event handler.

**Update2:** Included code example so it's not a link only answer.

Comment: Using the 'Vanish' element does not serve my purpose for the following two reasons : 1) should the user of the document choose to select some data and unknowingly end up deleting my inserted text. 2) Should the user choose to clear all formatting.

Comment: I feel that this is what I was looking for. I would just go thru your suggested link.

Comment: Since I received your updates, I checked them up and tried to use them. I added the custom xml part also. Then when I tried to figure out how to use it, I realized that I could probably use it only by binding it to content controls. Now my requirement is that with each paragraph written in this word document, I should be able to store some hidden information (eg, a per paragraph internal id - coming from some other source). Can this be achieved @Paul Zahra

Comment: @user3282758 You could probably store it in the StyleName... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850838%28v=office.15%29.aspx#sampleCode

Comment: The problem in storing in StyleName is that if that if the user opts to 'clear all formatting', the formatting is lost. I tried creating a new style - it didnt word for the above reason. @Paul Zahra

Comment: I was also trying to use SetAttribute method on the Wordprocessing.Text object. It saves the attribute when I run the code. But when the word document is opened and saved, the attribute is lost @Paul Zahra

Comment: @user3282758 Give the paragraph an id... it is supported.. look into setting divId. Or put a bookmark on the paragraph.. Or rap the paragraph in a content control :p

Comment: Can not wrap the paragraph in content control because he document has to appear as a normal usable word document to the user. But let me check other option suggested by you. I appreciate your support @Paul Zahra

Comment: I checked the paragraphId and the divId options - again as soon as the generated document is openend and saved, these are also lost @Paul Zahra

Comment: @user3282758 if it regenerated everytime u look at it then you can never put anything in it that will be 'saved' because it is 'new' everytime?

Comment: Sorry @PaulZahra, but I could not understand what is the meaning of your reply. Could you please specify it more clearly. It might be useful to me.

Comment: @user3282758 You said the document is regenerated, did you mean opened / read? Regenerated = "To become formed or constructed again."

Comment: Actually @PaulZahra, what I mean is not regeneration. I mean that when I generate a word document programatically with paragraph attributes and ids and divId, everything is saved properly. But then when this document is opened in MSWord and then saved, all this information is lost. Thus this hidden information saved as paragraphId etc is lost.